# Overriding p-dropdown css

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, primeng

Hi I have a requirement where I have to make dropdown option of a p-dropdowm to drop upwards. I was able to override css and make them drop upwards however when I click on dropdown, it initially drops options downwards and then applies my style and takes it upwards.

I want it to drop upwards as I click.

I have attached the overidden styles . Please help

**CSS**

```
::ng-deep .ui-dropdown-panel.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-shadow{
    transform: translateY(-189px) !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Add your code, don´t post as image. It is hard to type it when you already have it.

Comment: Instead of using PrimeNG [p-dropdown](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown) you can try ngx-bootstrap [Dropup variation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns) dropdowns. This is may be what you need instead of trying to modify the original  PrimeNG one.